# Java Thread completion status

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I have 2 threads `t1` and `t2`, each one performs individual tasks.

I want to start thread t2 after 60% completion of task in thread t1.

Could anyone has any idea how can I achieve it ?

Comment: How should we know it's 60% completion? You provided no releavent code and we can't be helpful.

Comment: Thats what my question is..Is there any built-in libraries in java thread to find out?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for a function _h(A)_ where _A_ is an _activation record_ for some arbitrary other function, _a(...)_; and you want _h(A)_ to compute how much time will elapse before the call to _a(...)_ returns.  Never mind that an activation record is not an object that you can _reflect_ on in Java.  The bigger obstacle is that you could use _h(A)_ to solve the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: You have to be able break down the tasks into measurable subtasks. Since you haven't posted any code, we can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException{
    Thread t = new Thread( new Task1() );

    t.start();

    t.join(0);

    //keep in mind that t2 can still be running at this point
    System.out.println("done running task1.");
}

public static class Task1 implements Runnable{

    public void run(){
        //Smimulate some long running job. In your case you need to have your own logic of checking if t1 is 60% done.
        //In this case we just wait 0.5 seconds for each 10% of work done
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

           try {  Thread.sleep(500); } 
           catch (InterruptedException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }   

           int percentComplete = i*10;

           System.out.println("Completed " + percentComplete + "%.");

           if (percentComplete == 60){
               new Thread( new Task2() ).start();  //this how to start t2 when we are 60% complete 
           }
        }            
    }
}

public static class Task2 implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //simulate t2 task that will run for 5 seconds. 

        System.out.println("task2 started.");

        try {  Thread.sleep(5000); } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); } 

        System.out.println("task2 is done.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can T1 know when it is 60% done?  If so, then why not have it start T2 at that time?

```
Thread t2 = null;

class T2task implements Runnable {
    ...
}

class T1task implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isNotFinished(...)) {
            if (isAtLeast60PercentDone(...) && t2 != null) {
                t2 = new Thread(new T2task(...));
                t2.start();
            }
            doSomeMoreWork(...);
        }
    }
}
```